# No instance for (Num (Maybe Size))

Tags: haskell, types

I'm compiling a Yesod site I'm building to make sure everything is working when I get this compiler error:

```
Foundation.hs:164:15:
    No instance for (Num (Maybe Size))
      arising from the literal `140'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (Maybe Size))
    In the `gSize' field of a record
    In the expression:
      GravatarOptions
        {gSize = 140, gDefault = Identicon, gForceDefault = False,
         gRating = PG}
    In an equation for `gs':
        gs
          = GravatarOptions
              {gSize = 140, gDefault = Identicon, gForceDefault = False,
               gRating = PG}
```

After reading the haddock documentation, I know that gSize takes a Maybe Size, and that Size is defined as:

```
newtype Size = Size Int
```

If it helps any here's the function in question.

```
import Yesod.Goodies.Gravatar
import Data.Text

gravatar :: Text -> Text
gravatar email =
  gravatarImg email gs
  where
    gs = GravatarOptions {
      gSize = 140
      , gDefault = Identicon
      , gForceDefault = False
      , gRating = PG
      }
```

I'm not sure where to start looking for a solution, could someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `gSize` is `Maybe Size`, then you need to use one of `Maybe` constructors — you can either use `Nothing` for no value or `Just x` for specified value. In your snippet, it should be `Just (Size 140)`, as in

```
gs = GravatarOptions {
  gSize = Just (Size 140)
  , gDefault = Identicon
  , gForceDefault = False
  , gRating = PG
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It says that it can't convert (through `Num` class) "140" to `Maybe Size`. You should use `gSize = Just (Size 140)` I guess